How to create text outline with gradient instead of solid color using CSS?
I would like to do this in css but instead of having gray in the outline, it would be a gradient.
Do you know how to do it?enter image description here
I did this in CSS, but I don't know how to do it in gradient :
<p class="text-outline">test</p>
<style>
.text-outline {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 
        -1px 0 0 gray,  
        1px 0 0 gray,
        0 -1px 0 gray,
        0 1px 0 gray;
    letter-spacing: -15px; 
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

